# CakePHP 3.x Filter Query results based on User Group / Organisation / Team

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, orm, authorization

I need to make sure that most of my models' queries return results based on User relation to the model (group member, organisation, member, team member).

In my app:

1. There are x organisations
2. There are x members of each organisation

I want data created by users to be accessible only if it was created within the same organisation.

Examples:

1. List all tasks that current member is related to (Role: User, ManyToMany w/ JoinTable)
2. List all tasks that are related to users of the same organisation
3. While editing task, list only users that are members of the same organisation
4. Absolutely prevent any depth of association to return results not associated with user organisation

   ```php
   class OrganizedBehavior extends Behavior {
       protected $_defaultConfig = [];

       public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, ArrayObject $options) {
           $modelName = $event->getSubject()->getAlias();
           if(isset($options['oid'])) {
               $query->where([$modelName.'.oid' => $options['oid']]);
           }
           return $query;
       }
   }
   ```

Can this be achieved using:

1. Overall Behavior?
2. Custom Middleware?
3. Authentication / Authorization class?
4. Anything better?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by externalizing your authorization and using a third-party framework. There is in fact an architectural approach called Attribute-Based Access Control ([abac](/questions/tagged/abac)) that will let you do this. In ABAC:

- you define policies e.g. `A user with role='X' can do action='view' on object of type='Y' if user.organization==object.organization`
- you define attributes that you will use in the policies e.g. role, department, location, organization.

There are a few standards and packages you can use to define your own policies such as XACML, ALFA, or OPA (REGO).

The overall architecture is as follows:

- Policy Enforcement Point (PEP): this is where your app integrates with the authorization service. The integration could be PHP code within your app calling out to the PDP or it could be middleware (like you said) or an API gateway...
- Policy Decision Point (PDP): this is where policies are evaluated against incoming authorization requests. The PDP eventually returns a decision (Permit / Deny) and optionally additional metadata which the PEP needs to process.
- Policy Information Point (PIP): this is where the PDP can fetch missing information (e.g. a user's risk score or department) in order to reach a decision.

This solution is not specific to PHP. There is a PHP-specific implementation you can [find here](https://packagist.org/packages/craftcamp/php-abac). Alternatively consider AuthZForce (open-source authorization service) or [Axiomatics](https://www.axiomatics.com) (commercial). Both can secure PHP apps as well as other languages.

[image: The Attribute-Based Access Control Architecture]